# Java splitting string at index without cutting the word

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was just wondering it here is an `API` or some easy and quick way to split `String` at given index into `String[] array` but if there is a word at that index then put it to other String.

So lets say I have a string: `"I often used to look out of the window, but I rarely do that anymore"`

The length of that string is **68** and I have to cut it at **36**, which is in this given sentence **n**, but now it should split the word at **the** so that the array would be `["I often used to look out of the", "window, but I rarely do that anymore"]`.

And if the new sentence is longer than **36** then it should be split aswell, so if I had a bit longer sentence: `"I often used to look out of the window, but I rarely do that anymore, even though I liked it"` 
Would be `["I often used to look out of the", "window, but I rarely do that anymore", ",even though I liked it"]`

Comment: @PM77-1 That question uses StringTokenizer. Now it can be done with String#split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an old-fashioned, non-stream, non-regex solution:

```
public static List<String> chunk(String s, int limit) 
{
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(s.length() > limit)
    {
        int splitAt = limit-1;
        for(;splitAt>0 && !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(splitAt)); splitAt--);           
        if(splitAt == 0) 
            return parts; // can't be split
        parts.add(s.substring(0, splitAt));
        s = s.substring(splitAt+1);
    }
    parts.add(s);
    return parts;
}
```

This doesn't trim additional spaces either side of the split point. Also, if a string cannot be split, because it doesn't contain any whitespace in the first `limit` characters, then it gives up and returns the partial result.

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] tests = {
            "This is a short string",
            "This sentence has a space at chr 36 so is a good test",
            "I often used to look out of the window, but I rarely do that anymore, even though I liked it",
            "I live in Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch",
    };

    int limit = 36;
    for(String s : tests)
    {
        List<String> chunks = chunk(s, limit);
        for(String st : chunks)
            System.out.println("|" + st + "|");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
|This is a short string|

|This sentence has a space at chr 36|
|so is a good test|

|I often used to look out of the|
|window, but I rarely do that|
|anymore, even though I liked it|

|I live in|
```

Answer (score 1):

This matches between 1 and 30 characters repetitively (greedy) and requires a whitespace behind each match.

```
public static List<String> chunk(String s, int size) {
    List<String> chunks = new ArrayList<>(s.length()/size+1);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".{1," + size + "}(=?\\s|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        chunks.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

Note that it doesn't work if there's a long string (>size) whitout whitespace.